# Office365 Sideload Outlook Add-In Install Fails

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, office365, outlook-addin

I'm testing if it's possible to create a Office 365 Outlook Add-in using Vue.js, so i saw the following guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-vue

And made the manifest adjustments on the generation to create it for Outlook instead of Excel, and of course removed Excel specific API code from the vue instance.

So i'm basically trying to sideload the generated Add-in to my Office365 Outlook:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing

And it fails... basically straight out of the box.

Is there any way to check logs to try and figure out why it's failing?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @bbsimonbb A generic Installation failed - The installation is taking longer than expected. If your add-in doesn't appear shortly, try installing it again.

Comment: ok. oy oy. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this specific problem by commenting the SupportUrl on the manifest.

Not sure if this will be the case for everyone with such a generic error, but i hope it helps someone.